# How to add attributes to forms?

Tags: theming, 8, forms

I am trying to style the registration/login forms so far I have copied all the files from `\drupal\core\themes\stable\templates\form\` to `themes\mytheme\template\form`.

Inside this folder, for example there is `input.html.twig` which has the following code.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override for an 'input' #type form element.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - attributes: A list of HTML attributes for the input element.
 * - children: Optional additional rendered elements.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_input()
 */
#}
<input{{ attributes }} />{{ children }}
```

My question is how can I add a specific class name to this input, so I can apply styles to it in my css file

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addClass()` method of the attribute class:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'my-class-1',
    'my-class-2',
  ]
%}

<input{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
```

You can either pass an array like the example above or pass a single class in the method directly: `attributes.addClass('my-class')`.

For reference see the Drupal docs: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/using-attributes-in-templates

Comment: Funny, I was just trying this and it does not work. I had to enclose the the the first portion of the code in `{%%}` though

Comment: Oh yeah, that's correct. Updated my anwer, thanks!